# Android Expandable list view - webpage

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am working on an android app. I finished my expandable list view and have every thing working. I want to add some more feature on the expandable list view.

What I want to do is. When the expandable list view is expanded, I want to click on the child and than lead me to a webpage.

Is there a method to do this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String url = "http://www.website.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Karim_Varela thanks for the reply. is there anyway to make each sublist to have a different website?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to use a ListAdapter to map a set of objects to your ListView. Each object could have a field for the website, or you could simply map to an ArrayList of Strings.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html